# Assign Session Variable during login in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-identity

I'm currently having a code in the `Login action`, so when the user login, it will pull some data from the database and store in a `Session` variable.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            {
                using (var db = new somedbContext())
                {
                    //do some query here

                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["userDepartment"] = departmentID; 
                }

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }    
    }
}
```

This works just fine if the user actually goes through the Login process. However, if the user tries to "login" with other means, such as using `cookie` (by remember me), or some browsers do save the credentials, or using a third party logins etc., this will not work anymore.

Where should I write the code and assign value to the `Session` so that regardless of where the user login from, it will go through the code?

Comment: This kind of stuff is why I just like to avoid using the session altogether.

Comment: Agreed, @emodendroket. It's especially thorny if you're using clusters. Maybe you ought to post an answer (maybe one already exists) for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the logic to lazy-initialize that session variable in a global filter based on [IAuthorizationFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter(v=vs.98).aspx).

The filter could be something like this:

```
public class SetDepartmentFilter : IAuthorizationFilter 
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var userInfo = GetUserInfo(filterContext);
        if (userInfo.IsAuthorized)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session["userDeparment"] = userInfo.Department;
        }
    }

    private UserInfo GetUserInfo(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // TODO: see if authorized, get department, etc.
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your application startup:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new SetDepartmentFilter());
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more

Comment: Do you have any link/tutorial on how to implement this?

Comment: How do I check if the user is Authorized? I cannot access any of the methods such as `User.Identity.GetuserId` etc.

Comment: You can get most of what you need from `filterContext.HttpContext`, for example, `filterContext.HttpContext.User`. You'll need to make sure this filter runs _after_ whatever process establishes the user.